# Preserve column settings in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Is there any way that I can preserve the group setting in ag-grid. I have the table using ag-grid and I collapsed all the group but expanded one group.
Change the data in one of row in the group and reload the data

```
self.propsGridGroupOpts.rowData = newData
self.propsGridGroupOpts.api.onNewRows();
```

all the columns in the table either expanded or collapse if these setting in gridOption

```
groupDefaultExpanded: true or
groupDefaultExpanded: false
```

Is there anyway that I can preserve my group setting(all groups are collapsed but one is expanded. The original state before reloaded the grid table
Thanks,
Kim

Comment: it would be nice to leave some kind of feedback

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/exampleKeepingGroupState.html

```
var gridOptions = {
...
    rememberGroupStateWhenNewData: true,
...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm usign Angular1 with Typescript. First, I'm creating a copy of the old dataset like this `let rowDataShallow = this.gridOptions.rowData;` Then I'm manipulating `rowDataShallow` and setting it as a new dataset like this `this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowDataShallow);` It seems to refresh the whole grid no matter how I set that `rememberGroupStateWhenNewData` property. I'll let you know if I come up with an answer.

Comment: That url is invalid.  Use this instead https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keeping-group-state

Comment: The property is no longer available in the newer versions of ag-Grid. You should go to this URL: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#changes-to-row-data